# How to restrict values in a list parameter of rest api method

Tags: java, rest

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/elcy/api")
public class DummyRestService {  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam List<String> statuses) {
        return "Hello RestService;
    }
}
```

I want to restrict that the list parameter statuses that it can have only "A","B" or "C" values and It doesn't allow value "D" or some other string value in the list.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of your code, especially the signature of the JAX-RS method. Which JAX-RS implementation and additional libraries do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of parameter statuses from List of String to List of Status where Status is Java Enum Type.

enum Status {A,B,C}

If value other then A,B or C is passed to restful method, Bad Request 400 error is generated.